# Converting PDF to any parse-able format

Tags: python, html, xml, pdf, text

I have a PDF file which consists of tables which can spread across various pages and may have text in between. An example of it can be found [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/prodprojfiles/0/753/753146/884574-sbc-cigna-connect-hsa-bronze-6000-denver-boulder-co+(1)_ac994d66-b06a-4ca9-b8f7-bee980597d36.pdf).
I am able to convert the PDF to any format but the output files are not in any way parse-able i.e. I cannot extract data out of it as they are scattered. Here are the links to the output files which I created using [pdftotext](http://hastebin.com/acifanonov.vhdl) and [pdftohtml](http://hastebin.com/xihekoweco.xml).

Is there a way to extract data in a more suitable way?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your sample file seems to have properly tagged data. Is it representative in that respect for all your documents?

Comment: Yes all my files are nearly in the same format. Can you tell me how it is properly tagged? That is exactly what I require to extract the tables.

Comment: *Can you tell me how it is properly tagged?* - When creating a PDF you have the option to insert machine-parsable tags in it to represent the structure of the contents. Your sample file does have these tags. Unfortunately I have no idea which python tools properly interpret those tags. I'd have an idea how to extract the data in Java.

Answer (score 1):

The general answer is no. `pdf` is a format intended for visual presentation and printing, and there is no guarantee that the contents will be in any particular order let alone structured as a table in any way other than what appears when the pdf is rendered onto paper or a screen. Sometimes there is even deliberate obfuscation to prevent anyone doing what you are attempting.

In this case it appears to be possible to cut and paste the contents of each table element. For a small number of similar files that is almost certainly the quickest thing to do. Open the pdf on the left hand of your screen, a spreadsheet or data-entry program on  the right hand, then cut and paste. For a medium number - tens, hundreds? - it's probably cheapest to hire a temp to do the donkey-work. For a large number - thousands? - it would be possible to create a program to automate this process, but definitely not easy. I might think about using human input via the mouse to identify the corners of the table and the horizontal / vertical divisions, then generating cut and paste operations via control of the human interface devices. Don't ask me how. I'd have to find out if I had to do this, and I'd much rather not. It's a WOMBAT.

Whatever form of analysis you did on the pdf contents would certainly not generalize to other pdfs created by different organisations using different software, and possibly not even by the same organisation using the same process but merely a later release of the same software.

Answer (score 1):

Following in the line of @nigel222, it really depends on the PDF how easily you can get the data out in some useful way.

It is best if the PDF is structured (has a document structure, created when the PDF was written). In this case, you can access the structure, and you are all set.

As structure is a fundamental necessity of an accessible PDF, you may try to "massage" the document by applying the various "make accessible" utilities floating around; definitely something to follow.